# Открыть submenu по клику

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть вот такой пример. Сейчас сабменю открывается по клику на любой `li`. Нужно чтобы открывало именно то сабменю которое находится непосредственно в этом `li`.

Код:

```js
$(function() {
 $('.main li').click(function(){
 $('.sub').slideToggle();
 })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="main">
  <li><a href="">1</a></li>
  <li>
     <a href="">2</a>
       <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="">1.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">1.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">1.3</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="">3</a></li>
   <li><a href="">4</a></li>
   <li><a href="">5</a></li>
</ul>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/brezze/pen/KZNXdz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$(function() {
    $('.main li').click(function() {
        $(this).find('.sub').slideToggle();
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Например:

```js
$('.main li a').click(function(e){   // клик на ссылку
 e.preventDefault();                // запрещаем переход по ссылке
 var item = $(this).closest('li');  // ищем li именно этой ссылки
 var sub = item.find('.sub');       // именно в этом пункте находим подменю
 sub.slideToggle();                 // развернуть\свернуть подменю
});
```

```css
.sub {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main">
  <li><a href="">1</a></li>
  <li>
     <a href="">2</a>
       <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="">1.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">1.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">1.3</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="">3</a></li>
   <li><a href="">4</a></li>
   <li><a href="">5</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Не знаю, почему отмечен был мой ответ, ведь ваш ответ был более полным.,.

Comment: @selya, это право автора, значит Ваш ему показался более приемлемым)